# How to delete the line that matches a pattern and the line after it with sed?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a file that looks something like:

```
good text
good text
FLAG bad text
bad text
good text
good text
good test
bad Text FLAG bad text
bad text
good text
```

I need to delete any line containing "FLAG" *and* I *always* need to delete the one line immediately following the "FLAG" line too.

"FLAG" lines come irregularly enough that I can't rely on any sort of line number strategy.

Anyone know how to do this with sed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using an extension of the `GNU` version of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -e '/FLAG/,+1 d' infile
```

It yields:

```
good text
good text
good text
good text
good test
good text
```

Comment: Perfect.  I was trying something like that, but couldn't guess the syntax correctly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This works, and doesn't depend on any extensions:

```
sed '/FLAG/{N
d
}' infile
```

`N` reads the next line into the pattern space, then `d` deletes the pattern space.

Comment: Much obliged.  Wish I could accept two answers here.  Gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way with `awk`:

```
awk '/FLAG/{f=1;next}f{f=0;next}1' file
```

or

```
awk '/FLAG/{getline;next}1' file
```