# Pattern Matching and Deleting four Lines corresponding to the pattern

Tags: python, sed, awk

I have 2 Files. File 1, has an Identifier (eg.**DF:1:1**). Then "1:N" is an additional field. The 2nd, 3rd and 4th lines are specific to the Identifier. File 2 consist of a column of Identifiers.
Logic: If the Identifier of File 2 is exactly matching with the Identifier of File 1 then, delete all the 4 Lines corresponding to that Identifier.

**File 1:**

```
@DF:1:1  1:N
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIA
+
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
@DF:1:2  1:N
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
AJJJJJJJJJJJJAA
@DF:1:3  1:N
TTTTTTTTTTCAACA
+
LLLLLLLLLLLLLLN
@DF:2:1  1:N
NNNNNNNNNNNNNGC
+
DHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
@DF:1:4  1:N
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
+
DFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

**File 2:**

```
DF:1:1
DF:1:3
DF:2:1
DF:9:9
DF:6:9
```

**Expected Output:**

```
@DF:1:2  1:N
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
AJJJJJJJJJJJJAA
@DF:1:4  1:N
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
+
DFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I am new in Bioinformatics and Programming and would Appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: My initial impulse would be to read the full `File2` in memory in an array (or a dict) and then open and read `File1` line by line, checking against the array and printing out (or not) the subsequent lines.

Comment: Can you explain me with the help of Codes as I am new to Programming. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[The following is based on the assumption that you don't have a <kbd>TAB</kbd> character in the input.]

You could make use of `paste` and `grep` to get the desired output:

```
paste - - - - < file1 | grep -F -v -f file2 | tr '\t' '\n'
```

The above joins 4 lines of `file1` (with tab as the delimiter), then removes the lines containing strings in `file2`.  Finally the tab characters are replaced with newlines.  For your sample input, this would produce:

```
@DF:1:2  1:N
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
+
AJJJJJJJJJJJJAA
@DF:1:4  1:N
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
+
DFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|/^@&\\s/,+3d|' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

Make a sed script from file2 to match on the key in file1 and delete the following 3 lines.

Comment: Good idea, I learn from this sed commands, but if the input file1 does not always have fixed 3 line each, then it will fail.

Comment: @BMW this solution is tailored to the contract `Pattern Matching and Deleting four Lines corresponding to the pattern`

Answer (score 0):

There are [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891125/deleting-multiple-lines-with-sed) along these lines (search for `sed delete multiple lines`).

As you can see, your options vary subtly between BSD sed (includes Mac) and GNU sed (Unix flavors).  Here's a clunky BSD version that works on my Mac:

```
cat bio_file2 | while read line; do sed -E "/$line/ {
N
N
N
d
}" bio_file1 > biof_tmp; mv biof_tmp bio_file1; done
```

It's clunky in not having an in-place modification option (`sed -i` on Unix), thus using a tmp file, and also in having to read the (`N`) next line into the pattern space instead of using the `gsed` shorter syntax -- passable for deleting 3 extra lines, not so great for e.g. deleting 100 extra lines.  Note the use of double quotes in order to use a shell variable to match against.

---

This is what I expect the GNU sed counterpart to look like:  (untested)

```
cat bio_file2 | while read line; do sed -i "/$line/,+3 d" bio_file1; done
```

---

If you were to have a situation of deleting the 100 lines after a match, one approach would be to find the matching line numbers 
    grep -n target somefile | awk -F: '{print $1}'

and then delete specifically those lines `i,i+100`.  But one needs to be careful to start with the highest line numbers in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' file2 RS=@ ORS=@ file1
```